# React Hook Form w/ FormProvider and MUI - Not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I have been trying to abstract my form components for some time now. I took the [example](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance) of `RHF JS` and rewrote it in Typescript.

Unfortunately, I do not get any output of the validation results. When I submit the form nothing happens either. My understanding is that I need to pass the FormContext through to the last component.

Can anyone with experience help me?

**App.tsx**

```js
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { memo } from "react";
import {
  FormProvider,
  useForm,
  useFormContext,
  UseFormReturn,
} from "react-hook-form";
import { object, SchemaOf, string } from "yup";

type FormData = {
  name: string;
};

const schema: SchemaOf<FormData> = object().shape({
  name: string()
    .required("Input is Required")
    .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "Only alphanummeric"),
});

type TextInputProps = {
  methods: UseFormReturn;
  name: string;
  label: string;
};

// we can use React.memo to prevent re-render except isDirty state changed
const TextFieldMemo = memo(
  ({ methods, name, label }: TextInputProps) => (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      error={!!methods.formState.errors[name]}
      helperText={
        (methods.formState.errors[name]?.message as unknown as string) ?? ""
      }
      fullWidth
      margin="normal"
      {...methods.register(name)}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
      FormHelperTextProps={{
        sx: {
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: "-1.5rem",
        },
      }}
    />
  ),
  (prevProps, nextProps) =>
    prevProps.methods.formState.isDirty ===
      nextProps.methods.formState.isDirty &&
    prevProps.methods.formState.errors !== nextProps.methods.formState.errors
);

export const TextFieldMemoContainer = () => {
  const methods = useFormContext();

  return <TextFieldMemo methods={methods} name="name" label="Name" />;
};

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const { isDirty } = methods.formState;
  const onSubmit = (form: FormData) => {
    console.log(isDirty);
    console.log(form);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Grid item>
            <TextFieldMemoContainer />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              disabled={
                !methods.formState.isDirty || !methods.formState.isValid
              }
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

[StackBlitz MRE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-iq7nsh)

Comment: Hello StackO community,
after submitting my question post, I found that the form works as it should. I can't explain this as I tested it extensively before during development. Sorry anyway for posting this ahead of time.